# Split one file into multiple files

Tags: c

I am doing this code to simulate external sort later, but I don't know what I'm doing wrong. Here's my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <string.h>

#define TAMANHO_ARQUIVO 10 // main file size
#define QTD_DISCOS 3       // number of files to divide the main file

int main () {

    FILE *arquivoPrincipal;  // main file
    int qtd_int = 0;
    int x = 0;
    char name[FILENAME_MAX];
    int memoria_interna = (int) ceil(TAMANHO_ARQUIVO/QTD_DISCOS);
    int vet[memoria_interna];

    arquivoPrincipal = fopen("arquivo.txt", "w+");

    srand(time(NULL));
    for (int i = 0; i < TAMANHO_ARQUIVO; ++i) {
      x = rand() % 10;
      fprintf(arquivoPrincipal, "%d\n", x);
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < QTD_DISCOS; ++i) {
      FILE *arquivo;
      snprintf(name, sizeof(name), "disco_%d.txt", i); // generating files dynamically          printf("%s\n", name);
      memset(vet, 0, sizeof vet); // clearing vector

      qtd_int = fread(&vet, sizeof(int), memoria_interna, arquivoPrincipal); // reading main file to get number of items from 0 to memoria_interna (which is the size of the main file / the number of files to be divided)
       //seeking/seting the position (for the next loop)
       fseek(arquivoPrincipal, qtd_int, SEEK_SET);

      arquivo = fopen(name, "w+");
      if (!arquivo) {
        printf("Error!\n");
        exit(0);
      }


      fwrite(&vet, sizeof(int), memoria_interna , arquivo);
      fclose(arquivo);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

My output is:
"arquivo.txt:

```
7
2
9
2
1
6
9
2
8
5
```

"disco_0.txt":
this file gets no values, it's a blank file.

"disco_1.txt":

```
0
0
3
1
9
7
```

"disco_2.txt":

```
3
1
9
7
9
7
```

What I expected was:

- "disco_0.txt" should have the first 3 elements (size of main file/qty of files)
- "disco_1.txt" should have another 3 elements
- "disco_2.txt" should have the last 4 elements

(Sorry for the Portuguese code).

Comment: `arquivo.txt` contains the text representation of numbers, why are you reading them with `fread()` into an `int` array? You should be using `fscanf()` to parse the fie.

Comment: You're also doing the first read from `arquivoPrincipal` before you use `fseek()`. So there's nothing to read, because you're at the end of the file after printing the numbers.

Comment: I don't understand why you're using the return value of `fread()` as the position to seek to.

Comment: It looks like you create the 'principal archive' from random numbers.  After writing those numbers, you should think about closing the file or flushing it. You need to rewind it before you try reading from it. Since you're writing text, you should read text; that means you should use `fgets()` and `sscanf()` — or just `fscanf()` if you prefer.  In this program, you know how many lines there are before you start.  When you come to external sorting, you won't necessarily know how many lines there are when you start reading the data.  You'll need to modify your code appropriately … later.

Answer (score 0):

From what I understand you wanted to split the main file into n's files.
What you can do is use is a loop with fscanf and save to a buffer the data, in the main loop, when it arrives in the last iteration, increment the limit of the loop that captures the ints, if there is a remainder of division of between TAMANHO_ARQUIVO/QTD_DISCOS The loop that captures the int's will be larger, so the last loop will save more int's than the others.

The fscanf function allows you to use parameters to capture integers, floats, chars, etc.

Using fread for this will make the task much more complicated.
Do not forget that to put the file pointer in the correct position we have to count the end of line.

No doubt there must be more practical ways of doing what you intend.
Any question I can write in pt-br.

```
#define TAMANHO_ARQUIVO 10 // main file size
#define QTD_DISCOS 3       // number of files to divide the main file

int main () 
{

    FILE *arquivoPrincipal;  // main file

    int x = 0;
    int incpos=0;
    char name[FILENAME_MAX];
    int memoria_interna = (int) ceilf(TAMANHO_ARQUIVO/QTD_DISCOS);
    char vet[256] ;
    printf("memoria_interna:%d remainder:%d \n",memoria_interna,TAMANHO_ARQUIVO%QTD_DISCOS);
    int remainder  = TAMANHO_ARQUIVO%QTD_DISCOS;
    arquivoPrincipal = fopen("arquivo.txt", "w+");
    int isLastDisco = memoria_interna-1;



    srand(time(NULL));
    for (int i = 0; i < TAMANHO_ARQUIVO; ++i) 
    {
        x = rand() % 10;
        fprintf(arquivoPrincipal, "%d\n", x);
    }

    fseek(arquivoPrincipal, 0 , SEEK_SET);/*reseta para a posição zero*/

    for (int i = 0; i < QTD_DISCOS; ++i) 
    {
        FILE *arquivo;
        int   numOfIntsTosave;
        int *pInts;
        sprintf(name,"disco_%d.txt", i); // generating files names dynamically          printf("%s\n", name);
        memset(vet, 0, 256); // clearing vector

        //qtd_int = fread(vet, sizeof(char), memoria_interna*2, arquivoPrincipal); 
        // reading main file to get number of items from 0 to memoria_interna (which is the size of the main file / the number of files to be divided)

        arquivo = fopen(name, "w");
        if (!arquivo) 
        {
            printf("Error!\n");
            exit(0);
        }
        if(i==QTD_DISCOS-1)/*If we are in the last iteration of the for loop, then if there is a remainder, we add to memoria_interna */
            numOfIntsTosave = memoria_interna+remainder;/*remainder this can be zero*/
        else
            numOfIntsTosave = memoria_interna;

        pInts = (int*)malloc(sizeof(int)*numOfIntsTosave);/*alloc buffer to int´s*/
        if(pInts==NULL){
            printf("error malloc\n");
            exit(0);
        }
        for(int u=0;u<numOfIntsTosave;u++)
        {
            fscanf(arquivoPrincipal,"%d\n",&pInts[u]);/*le do arquivo principal*/
            fprintf(arquivo, "%d\n", pInts[u]);/*salva no arquivo*/
            incpos+=2;/* um int e um /n */
        }
        if(pInts)
            free(pInts);/*free buffer of int´s*/
        incpos+=2;/* um int e um /n */
        //fwrite(vet, sizeof(char), qtd_int , arquivo);//printf("Error!\n");
        fclose(arquivo);

        /*seeking/seting the position (for the next loop)*/
        fseek(arquivoPrincipal,incpos, SEEK_SET);

    }
    fclose(arquivoPrincipal);

    return 0;
}
```